# Office365 Exchange reports API error - Resource not found for the segment 'MailDetailDlpPolicy'

Tags: office365

We've been getting this error when we try to read from the Exchange Reports API

```
{"odata.error":
   {"code":"",
    "message":
       {"lang":"en-US",
        "value":"Resource not found for the segment 'MailDetailDlpPolicy'."
       }
   }
}
```

As we're monitoring several environments, we only see this for some environments, but not all. roughly 15% of them.

Is this API being deprecated?
Any other potential cause for this?

Thanks